# Filter array of mixed values to different array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have array,

```
arr = [1, 2, "a", "a1", "3", "qw7", "b", "4", "xyz", "abcd"]
```

i like to filter it to according to its content iterate over each find out whether its alphabet character or number, filter out alphanumeric values to separate array, numeric to separate and alphabets to separate,

```
out1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
out2= ["a", "b", "x", "y", "z", "c", "d"]
out3= ["a1", "qw7"]
```

i can do for `out1`, cant for `out2` and `out3`

```
out1 = arr.filter(Number) // to get required output, [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

i tried using,

```
arr.map( i=>{
   if (i typeof string){
      out2.push(i);
   }
})
```

Comment: Where are the attempts to solve the other two conditions? Surely you did some research and tried something?

Comment: Man you selected an answer before I could even finish writing mine xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, "a", "a1", "3", "qw7", "b", "4", "xyz", "abcd"]

const filterNumeric = (arr = []) =>
  arr.filter(e => /^[0-9]+$/.test(e));
const filterAlphabetic = (arr = []) =>
  new Set([...
    arr.filter(e => /^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(e)).flatMap(str => str.split(''))
  ]);
const filterAlphaNumeric = (arr = []) =>
  arr.filter(e => /^[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+$/.test(e));
  
console.log("numeric: ",      ...filterNumeric(arr));
console.log("alphabetic: ",   ...filterAlphabetic(arr));
console.log("alpa-numeric: ", ...filterAlphaNumeric(arr));
```

Comment: As far as I can understand, according to the OP request, strings containing only alphabetic characters should be split into single characters and duplicated values should be removed so, `alphabetic` should be `['a','b','x','y','z','c','d']`

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following way:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, "a", "a1", "3", "qw7", "b", "4", "xyz", "abcd"]

// use map() to convert the string number to number
var out1 = arr.filter(Number).map(c => Number(c));
console.log(out1);

// use flatMap() and split() with filter, regex test() and set
var out2 = [...new Set(arr.filter(i => /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(i)).flatMap(c => c.split('')))];
console.log(out2);

// use filter with rezex test()
var out3 = arr.filter(i => /^[a-zA-Z]+\d+$/.test(i));
console.log(out3);
```

Answer (score 2):

To filter out alpha characters you can use:

```js
const out2= ["a", "b", "x", "y", "z", "c", "d", 1]

console.log(out2.filter(a => a.toString().match(/^[A-Za-z]/)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group your array based on regex for number, character and alphanumeric.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, "a", "a1", "3", "qw7", "b", "4", "xyz", "abcd"],
      result = arr.reduce((r,v) => {
        if(String(v).match(/^\d+$/)) {
          r.number.push(v);
        } else if(v.length === 1 && v.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
          r.character.push(v);
        } else {
          r.alphaNumeric.push(v);
        }
        return r;
      },{number: [], character: [], alphaNumeric: []});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: As far as I can understand, according to the OP request, string representing numbers should be converted into number and strings containing only alphabetic characters should be split into single characters and duplicated values should be removed so, the output should be `{ number: [1,2,3,4], character: ['a','b','x','y','z','c','d'], alphaNumeric: ['a1','qw7'] }`

Answer (score 2):

You could check the type and push to the wanted array.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, "a", "a1", "3", "qw7", "b", "4", "xyz", "abcd"],
    result = array.reduce((r, v) => {
        switch (true) {
            case isFinite(v): 
                r.numbers.push(+v);
                break;
            case /^[a-z]+$/i.test(v.toString()):
                [...v.toString()].forEach(c => {
                    if (!r.alphabet.includes(c)) r.alphabet.push(c);
                });
                break;
            default:
                r.misc.push(v);
        }
        return r;
    }, { numbers: [], alphabet: [], misc: [] });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: As far as I can understand, according to the OP request, strings containing only alphabetic characters should be split into single characters and duplicated values should be removed so, `letters` should be `['a','b','x','y','z','c','d']`

Comment: Nina no joke I just quoted you on another answer yesterday for your wordify function lol

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the issue with a single loop, doing something like this:

```js
function splitByType(arr) {
  const allChars = []
  const allStrings = []
  const allNums = []

  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (typeof item === 'number' || /^[0-9]+$/.test(item)) {
      const n = typeof item === 'number' ? item : Number(item);
      allNums.push(n);
    } else if (/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(item)) {
      allChars.push(...item.split(''));
    } else {
      allStrings.push(item)
    }
  });

  return {
    chars: [...new Set(allChars)],
    strings: [...new Set(allStrings)],
    nums: [...new Set(allNums)]
  }
}

//test
const input = [1, 2, "a", "a1", "3", "qw7", "b", "4", "xyz", "abcd"];

const { chars, strings, nums } = splitByType(input);

console.log('input:', input);
console.log('chars:', chars);
console.log('nums:', nums)
console.log('strings:', strings)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should account for all the cases you're looking for. A few notes on each case here:

1. `out1` :: In your first case, to convert any numerical strings to numbers, you will also need to use the array `map` method, but you can exclude that if you don't mind leaving some of the numbers as strings.
2. `out2` :: For your second case, in order to get all letters separated for your `out2`, we will need to `join` and then re-`split` the strings. To remove any duplicates, we use a `filter` method, though you could also use this more ES6 Set method if you like: `[...new Set(arr)]`
3. `out3` :: For your third and final case, we can use a very similar filter to the one we used for `out2` but instead of checking that `every` character is NOT a number, we check to make sure that `some` are numbers. We also remove the `join` and `split` we used, as the desired result for `out3` are multi-character strings.

Here are my functions:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, "a", "a1", "3", "qw7", "b", "4", "xyz", "abcd"]

const out1 = arr.filter(Number).map(Number)
// -> [1, 2, 3, 4]

const out2 = arr.filter(e => !Number(e) && e.split('').every(f => !Number(f))).join('').split('').filter((e,i,a) => a.indexOf(e) === i)
// -> ["a", "b", "x", "y", "z", "c", "d"]

const out3 = arr.filter(e => !Number(e) && e.split('').some(f => Number(f))).filter((e,i,a) => a.indexOf(e) === i)
// -> ["a1", "qw7"]
```

Feel free to test any of these methods in the demo I've set up below. Adjust the input array however you like and then select the method using the select box:

```js
const filter1 = arr => arr.filter(Number).map(Number);
const filter2 = arr => arr.filter(e => !Number(e) && e.split('').every(f => !Number(f))).join('').split('').filter((e,i,a) => a.indexOf(e) === i);
const filter3 = arr => arr.filter(e => !Number(e) && e.split('').some(f => Number(f))).filter((e,i,a) => a.indexOf(e) === i);

arrFilters = {
  filter1: arr => filter1(arr),
  filter2: arr => filter2(arr),
  filter3: arr => filter3(arr)
};

const input = document.getElementById('input');
const filter = document.getElementById('filter');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

const processInput = () => {
  try {
    output.value = JSON.stringify(arrFilters[filter.value](JSON.parse(input.value)));
    console.log(`${filter.value} output: ${JSON.stringify(arrFilters[filter.value](JSON.parse(input.value)))}`);
  } catch (e) {
    output.value = "";
  }
}
processInput();

input.addEventListener('input', processInput);
filter.addEventListener('change', processInput);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
input, select {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input:not(:last-child), select:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
Input Array
<input id="input" value='[1, 2, "a", "a1", "3", "qw7", "b", "4", "xyz", "abcd"]'>

Filter Method
<select id="filter">
  <option value="filter1">Filter #1 - Retrieve Numeric</option>
  <option value="filter2">Filter #1 - Retrieve Alphabetical</option>
  <option value="filter3">Filter #1 - Retrieve Alpha-Numeric</option>
</select>

Output Array
<input id="output" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: Thanks Brand, for your time, Thanks Alot

Comment: @AshishKamble no problem! I encourage you to run the code snippet above and try it out. The three functions I wrote are very short and simple. You can use regex to do a lot of this but sometimes regex checks slow down computation and your requirements were very simple so I steered away from regex.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to get 3 arrays with unique values is to use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

You can loop though the array and check for numbers or alpha using a pattern `[a-z]` using a case insensitive match with the `/i` flag.

To check for only alphanumeric, you can use a pattern `^(?=[a-z\d]*[a-z])[a-z\d]*\d[a-z\d]*$` to check that the string contains at least a char a-z and a digit

```js
const num = new Set(),
  alpha = new Set(),
  alNum = new Set();
const arr = [1, 2, "a", "a1", "3", "qw7", "b", "4", "xyz", "abcd"];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

  const item = arr[i];

  if (isFinite(item)) {
    num.add(+item);
    continue;
  }
  if (/^[a-z]+$/i.test(item)) {
    item.split('').forEach(alpha.add, alpha);
    continue;
  }
  if (/^(?=[a-z\d]*[a-z])[a-z\d]*\d[a-z\d]*$/i.test(item)) {
    alNum.add(item)
  }
}

console.log(Array.from(num));
console.log(Array.from(alpha));
console.log(Array.from(alNum));
```